# Can a subspace S containing vectors with a finite number of nonzero components contain the zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A set S consists of those vectors with a finite number of nonzero components.

Given a vector space V with infinite dimensions, or $V = R^\infty$, I am trying to prove that the set S is a subspace of it.

This is Problem 18 in Section 7.1 (Vector Spaces and Subspaces), [page 285](https://books.google.com/books?id=tWYdBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA285), from Linear Algebra by Jeffrey Holt.

---

By definition, to be a subspace, S must:

1. Contain the zero vector
2. Be closed under vector addition
3. Be closed under scalar multiplication

I immediately want to say that this proof is false because of the first point above with the zero vector. Since S consists of those vectors with a finite number of nonzero components, it makes me think that it cannot contain the zero vector which would have the same number of components as S, with all of them being 0 (e.g. The zero vector contains a finite number of zero components!)

Can someone help me understand this better? Is my logic correct?

Comment: $R^\infty$ is not a good notation, nor a legit one, AFAIK.

Comment: And, what do you mean by component?

Comment: What does it mean for the zero vector to "have the same number of components as $S$?" Can you give some examples of elements in $S$ and explain why the zero vector does not fit this description?

Comment: Sorry, that is how my [textbook](https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Applications-Jeffrey-Holt/dp/0716786672/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1478124258&sr=1-1&keywords=linear+algebra+with+applications+holt) wrote the question.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli Matt I am trying to show that S is a subspace, which means it must contain the zero vector. For it to be a member of S, it must have the same number of components as a vector in S. So if S is in $R^3$, a valid vector would <1, 2, 3>

Comment: Well one is still OK. The zero vector has 0 non-zero components, and 0 is finite. I think the answer should be yes.

Comment: @zhughes3 If you start with a vector space $V=\mathbb{R}^\infty$ (all infinite sequences of real numbers), then a subspace of $V$ must be, first and foremost, a subset of $V$.  That is, all elements of $S$ must also be infinite sequences of real numbers.  The example of $<1,2,3>$ does not belong here since this vector is not contained in $V$.  However, the vector $(1,2,3,0,0,0,\dots)$ is contained in $V$.

Comment: @WillFisher Wow! That did not occur to me. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @zhughes3 I just want to make sure you understand what the zero vector in $V$ (and thus $S$) looks like... the zero vector is not the number $0$ or a vector $<0>$, but rather a sequence consisting of all $0$'s: $(0,0,0,0,0,\dots)$. This is very important to understand here so be careful when you write up this proof!

Comment: @Matt First off, thank you for spending time on this to help me. For some reason, I was under the impression that if you have some vector space V with dimension n, then a valid subspace of V can have lower dimension. [Check out this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace) , particularly the first sentence.

Comment: @Matt After doing some searching on here, I have found more explanation regarding subspace having to be a subset which implicitly implies that the spaces must have same number of dimensions as the parent space. I will remember this for the future. Also, I will post my answer to this question to see what you think. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, I gathered from your comments that there may have been some misunderstanding. Be careful with dimension, since this is a very rigid mathematical concept. For example, if I start with $\mathbb{R}^3$ (a 3 dimensional space), then the set $\{ (a,0,0) : a\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a subspace. In fact, this is a 1D subspace. So, subspaces indeed *may have different dimensions*, but since they are subsets, they still "live" in 3D space. Dimension is simply a notion of how many degrees of freedom a space has.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47907/discussion-between-zhughes3-and-matt).

Answer (score 1):

Your headline question is poorly phrased. Your longer description is better, though please note the comments about notation.

$S$ is a subspace. Let's look at the 3 rules.

1. $0 \in S$. Of course it is, it has a finite number of nonzero components, i.e. $0$ of them!
2. $s,t \in S \implies s+t \in S$. The indices of the nonzero components of $s+t$ is at most the union of the indices for $s$ and $t$, hence finite.
3. $s \in S \implies \lambda s \in S$ for any scalar $\lambda$. Becuase we have already covered off the zero vector, we may assume $\lambda \neq 0$. Then the zero components of $s$ and $\lambda s$ are identical.

Comment: In this particular context, can I interpret "s + t is at most the union of the indices for s and t" as "s + t is at most the sum of the indices for s and t"?

Comment: Not really. I should have been more precise. Let $s_i$ be the $i$-th component of s. $i$ is the index. For $(s+t)_i$ to be nonzero, at least one of $s_i$ and $t_i$ must be nonzero. This can only occur a finite number of times.